# Windows: get the path of an exe by application name or identifier?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In macOS, it's possible to get the full path of an application via its bundle ID by using the `absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier` method of `NSWorkspace`. Does Windows have a similar API that allows getting the full path of an executable using its file name without performing a search of the filesystem, or perhaps by using some other kind of identifier?

Comment: Windows doesn't have any concept of a "bundle", so your question doesn't make much sense in that environment - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'd like to get the full path of an executable given the executable's filename without resorting to a full search of the filesystem. For example, get `C:\Program Files\SomeApp\someapp.exe` using the string `someapp.exe`. Alternatively, if Windows provides another better way of identifying a specific application that I could use instead of a filename, that would be even better, though as far as I'm aware it doesn't have anything like that. (I've edited my question to clarify these points.)

Comment: Get the full path of the executable from where? I.E from what program?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: That's incorrect. UWP applications *do* have an app identity, and are deployed, managed and maintained as bundles. Prior to UWP, [the directory \[was\] the application bundle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110620-00/?p=10393).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no global application database you can query for all installed applications. I assume UWP/Store apps are registered somewhere but classic applications do not have to do that.

Some applications register themselves under the [app paths key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#appPaths) in the registry.

> The entries found under App Paths are used primarily for the following purposes:
>
> • To map an application's executable file name to that file's fully qualified path.
>
> • To pre-pend information to the PATH environment variable on a per-application, per-process basis.

Not all applications are registered there. You might want to search the directories listed in %Path% as well.

Comment: A COM object server that is implemented as an EXE can have its full path be found in the Registry by its CLSID identifier, usually in the `HKCR\CLSID\<clsid>\LocalServer(32)` value, or the `<csidl>` key may have a ProgID that maps to a `HKCR\<ProgID>` key, or an AppID that maps to a `HKCR\AppID\<appname>` key, either of which may have the EXE file path.

Comment: Applications can also register the executable name as a ProgId with a default verb (typically "open") and a command template. You can query the executable path in this case via `AssocQueryStringW(ASSOCF_INIT_BYEXENAME, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, szExecutableName, NULL, szPath, pcchPath)`.

Comment: If you know the application friendly name, the central registry for default applications is under "[HKLM|HKCU]\Software\RegisteredApplications". Each value has the path of an application's "Capabilities" key relative to the hive root (i.e. HKLM or HKCU), where you'll find the "ApplicationName" value and possible subkeys for FileAssociations and URLAssociations that map file extensions and protocols to ProgIds. You can get the executable path for a ProgId via `AssocQueryStringW(ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, szProgId, NULL, szPath, pcchPath)`.